# get timezone list by PST EDT etc

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I need to get timezone by name from PST, PDT, EST etc information. Such as

`EST` = `America/New_York`
 `PDT` = `America/Los_Angeles`

I have `PST`, `EST` string and I need a standard timezone like above within this timezone area. How can I achieve this? So it will like this **When I get EST it will generate America/New_York When PDT it will generate America/Los_Angeles etc..**

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function for that: [timezone_name_from_abbr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-name-from-abbr.php)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not do this.  Time zone abbreviations are often ambiguous.  CST has 5 different interpretations, etc.    [See this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).

Functions like `timezone_name_from_abbr` exist in PHP, but they only return the first of the time zones that happen to match.

See these related questions:

- [timezone_name_from_abbr() not recognizing correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19622213/634824)
- [Get longer time zone name in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30944545/634824)

Comment: `timezone_name_from_abbr()` not working properly. Any solution for this?

Comment: Don't try to parse a time zone abbreviation.  It may work in some contexts, but it will fail in those you're not considering.